# My xpath query string doesn´t work

Tags: html-parsing, xquery

I would like to grab the following value on this website with [xquery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/). After trying for awhile I couldn't figure it out. Here is what I am trying to fetch ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKgoF.jpg))

[image: example of what I want to grab]

And the code I tried using:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "???????????????" );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to grep the value between script tags 
Like

```
//form/div/div/div[@class="values span-7"]/skipt/Text()
```

After parse the value in PHP other language hat you use to get your string

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the value off of the input?

```
//form//input[@name="val7"]/@value
```

Update:

You can get the stuff in the script tag, but that's as far as you can get using xpath. You'll then need to parse the contents of the script tag in order to get that value.

```
//form[@id="werte"]//div[@class="calval7"]//div[@class="values"][1]/script/text()
```

Comment: No ... that´s my problem. I don´t know how can i extract the value from the java script with xpath query